# Dbeaver is not creating tables for me

Tags: java, database

I am a novice when it comes to programming, I was trying to connect a Spring project to DBeaver, and I entered the path of where I have the project in the appropriate field to create the connection.

I have entities in the project that however are not reported on DBeaver even if the connection is successful. In the part of the properties.yml where the auto-ddl field is present, I gave update or create-drop as a value, but the tables are still not generated, could someone tell me the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.